# How to allow different updates - Meteor collection.allow

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

I want to allow users to update a collection in more than one way.

What is the best way to allow users to update and have different checks?

I want to do something like this:

```
Articles.allow({
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    if (modifier.$push.savedBy === Meteor.userId()) {
      console.log('User is saving an article.');
      return true;
    }
    if (Meteor.userId() && Math.abs(modifier.$inc.score) === 1) {
      console.log('User ALLOWED to vote on the article' + doc.title);
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('User DISALLOWED from updating the article' + doc.title);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Is there another way other than writing methods?

Comment: So what goes wrong if you try this? Are there error messages?

Comment: What happens is that it throws: '/articles/update' TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm uncertain if I'm answering your question, but you can make multiple `allow` and `deny` callbacks for the same collection:

```
Articles.allow({
  update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    return (modifier.$push != null) && modifier.$push.savedBy === userId;
  }
});

Articles.allow({
  update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    return (userId != null) && (modifier.$inc != null) && (Math.abs(modifier.$inc.score) === 1);
  }
});
```

The logic works as follows: If **any** of the `allow` callbacks return `true`, and **none** of the `deny` callbacks return `true`, then the operation will succeed.

Comment: So I tried this but in reversed order.  What happens is that it throws: `'/articles/update' TypeError: Cannot read property 'score' of undefined`.

Comment: I haven't tried it like this, but I imagine it will throw 'Cannot read property 'savedBy' of undefined.  I'll try it just in case there's unexpected behavior.

Comment: Looks like $inc.score is the culprit here.  After taking that check out these multiple allow verifications work in either order.  Now I wonder what that's about...

Comment: Yeah I just slightly reworked your code to show how it *could* work - this probably isn't literally what you should use. It's no surprise that you'd get a type error - you'd get that any time that `$inc` or `$push` were not defined on `modifier`. Maybe try something like: `return (userId != null) && (modifier.$inc != null) && (Math.abs(modifier.$inc.score) === 1);`

Comment: Yes, these modifiers are the source of my difficulty.  Thanks for helping me figure this out.  Going to mark your answer as accepted/correct.  Perhaps you could make it more clear the original source of my problem in your answer for others in the future.

Comment: @JohnAllen for the unexpected inputs have a go at using `check` since it will outright deny anything which is unexpected.