# Meteor allow/ deny rules

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

I'm about to set the allow/ deny rules for an application.
There are some apps that set both allow and deny rules. Why would I do that?
In my opinion it's the same thing. So it doesn't matter if you say "You can delete if you own this document" or "You can't delete if you don't own this document".

So why set both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one `allow` or `deny` rule then you are correct - it doesn't matter which one you use. However, if you have [multiple rules for the same operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752090/how-to-allow-different-updates-meteor-collection-allow) you can express more complex logic.

When evaluating the rules, a decision is reached as follows: If **any** of the `allow` callbacks return true, **AND** **none** of the `deny` callbacks return true, then the operation will succeed.

Comment: Thanks! Could you have a look at my rules? I want to filter out any properties that are not wanted using _.pick() but it doesn't work /:

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful. I'd recommend creating a separate question which shows the code for that specific rule.

Comment: Actually forgot to paste the link .. Could you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395189/meteor-filtering-properties-on-insert-doesnt-work