# Meteor: Filtering properties on insert doesn't work

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

I'd like to filter properties that are coming from the client but not wanted when creating new documents. I tried to use underscore's _.pick() but it seems like I can't override *doc*.

```
Meteor.Collection.prototype.addTimestamps = function () {

  this.deny({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
      doc.createdAt = Date.now();
      doc.updatedAt = Date.now();
      return false;
    },
    update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
      modifier.$set.updatedAt = Date.now();
      return false;
    },
  });

};


Entries.addTimestamps();
Entries.allowed = ['_id', 'content', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt'];

Entries.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    doc = _(doc).pick(Entries.allowed);
    doc.userId = userId;
    return !! userId;
  },

  update: function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
    return doc.userId === userId;
  },

  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    return doc.userId === userId;
  }
});
```

Comment: You *can* get this sort of thing to work, but I'd recommend using a method instead. This is just my opinion, but it seems confusing to be manipulating the document in an allow callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing to `doc` in the line

```
doc = _(doc).pick(Entries.allowed);
```

You're overwriting the `doc` **variable** so that it no longer points to the actual `doc` object. What you want is to change the **object** itself.

You need to `delete` all the `doc` properties that are not whitelisted. Example implementation:

```
insert: function(userId, doc) {
  var keys = _.keys(doc);
  keys = _.difference(keys, Entries.allowed);
  _.each(keys, function(key) {
    delete doc[key];
  });
}
```